# Power BI- Comparing data

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

imagine the scenario of the sales data per store per month on the table below

[image: Table]

Is there any way that I would select a store from Slicer it would compare its individual sales on all month vs the average sales of all stores on all months.

For example: if I select Store B from slicer, then I want a graph that would compare `(3,4,5,8)` vs `(10,11,12,7)`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Measure to calculate the average across all stores, something like:

```
Avg All Stores = CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( MyTable[Sales] ) , ALL ( MyTable[Store] ) )
```